# Generate string data from regex

Tags: python-hypothesis

I would like to be able to take a regex and generate conforming data using the python hypothesis library. For example given a regex of

```
regex = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]')
```

This would match any english alpha characters. An example generator for this could be.

```
import hypothesis
import string

hypothesis.strategies.text(alphabet=string.ascii_letters)
```

But Ideally I want to construct a string that will match any regex passed in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a [work in progress pull request](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/pull/393) for adding this feature.  Nothing extant will let you do it easily, but looking at the PR might give you a good idea about how to translate any specific example you need.

*Update: the [`from_regex`](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html#hypothesis.strategies.from_regex) strategy was added in Hypothesis 3.19.*